How to effectively abort a GraphQL FastAPI API in Python after a specified timeout
Iam developing a GraphQL API using Graphql and FastAPI, and I'm encountering issues with handling long-running requests.
My goal is to abort a request if it exceeds a specified timeout (e.g.10-15 seconds) to improve the responsiveness of the API.
Context:
I have a GraphQL endpoint that performs a database query which may take a variable amount of time depending on the input parameters.
I want to ensure that if the query takes too long, the API will return a timeout error instead of hanging indefinitely.
Example:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
import asyncio
app = FastAPI()
@app.post("/xyz")
async def xyz(xyz_input:xyzRequest):
try:
# Simulate a long-running operation
result = await asyncio.wait_for(long_running_task(), timeout=5)
return result
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
raise HTTPException(status_code=408, detail="Request timed out")

To make sure you actually limit database resource use, I would suggest implementing a timeout on the database level. What database are you using, and how are you connecting to it? Any ORM or similar?

Thank you for the response.         Database is alloydb(postgres), Yes I am using sqlalchemy ORM classes and connecting to db by creating engine using sqlalchemy. May I know why can't I apply timeout abortion for graphql-fastapi API's I tried 2 ways using asyncio.wait_for for APIs and one more is timeout middleware but by both also I was not able to.abort the APIs.

I've never used alloydb, but in postgres, you can set a "statement timeout", which means that any query running for longer than X seconds will terminate in an error. See e.g. this question for how it can be implemented in SQLAlchemy. You can then catch this error in your application and return an HTTP error response.

Okay thank you I will try out this
